# How to run code on Exit vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would just like to know how to run code in vb.net when the program is closed with the red cross in the top right of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Form.FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) - Read the `Remarks` on this event documentation for better implementation of your functionality.

> It occurs before the form is closed.

Check [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) properties for further manipulations:

**e.CloseReason**

**e.Close**

> However, canceling the event will set to true the Cancel property of
>   the FormClosingEventArgs class that is passed as a parameter to the
>   parent form. To force all MDI parent and child forms to close, set the
>   Cancel property to false in the MDI parent form.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            sr.WriteLine("8 - FormClosing");
        }
```

[Windows Forms Events Lifecycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/windows-forms-events-lifecycle/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event: use the CloseReason property of the [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) to determine why the form is closing - you want to look for CloseReason.UserClosing - and set the Cancel property to true if you want to cancel the form close.